# mtd device must be supplied

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04, and I'm receiving this error while booting:

```
[ 21.752361] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

The system initializes without further problems, but it's quite annoying. Someone said that running these commands should solve the problem:

```
cp /{lib,etc}/systemd/system/systemd-pstore.service\
sed -i '<email address hidden> //' /etc/systemd/system/systemd-pstore.service\
systemctl daemon-reload
```

My question is:
Why do I receive an error when I run:

```
sed -i '<email address hidden> //' /etc/systemd/system/systemd-pstore.service
```

?

I know I should replace an email address, but how do I know which email address that is?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error, but my system doesn't boot at all.

For your problem, see
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1981622

The bugfix should be released soon.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem and I solved it by booting into recovery mode, and making the distribution upgrade using the following command:

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Hope this can help.