# What should go here "<email address hidden>"?

Tags: command-line

Several times over the years I have seen solutions on Ask Ubuntu which include the in the command "email address hidden>" as in `sed -i '<email address hidden> //' /etc/systemd/system/systemd-pstore.service` in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423079/mtd-device-must-be-supplied)

What "email address", or other text, is actually required here?

Answer (score 3):

> What "email address", or other text, is actually required here?

Some text that includes an `@` sign which was incorrectly detected by some sort of cleanup script or content filter as an email address.

What exact text that is cannot be said without knowing the precise problem and the precise contents of the file being edited.

In this particular case, the code is copied from this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1981622/. Launchpad automatically hides everything which looks like an email address from anonymous users. Only logged in users can see the unmangled version:

> ```sh
> sed -i 's/modprobe@mtdpstore.service //' /etc/systemd/system/systemd-pstore.service
> ```

Comment: Thanks. So what text do you think should be included in the example thread I included above?

Comment: The text that was removed by whatever tool removed the text.

Comment: So some solutions on Ask Ubuntu are being rendered useless by software used by Ask Ubuntu, but are still being published on the Ask Ubuntu website in their useless state? That doesn't seem very sensible to me, but maybe I'm missing somrthing here.

Comment: I don't know who or what is replacing those strings. *Something*, at *some time* has replaced those strings. That is all I know. Maybe it is a browser plugin that the person posted the answer used. Maybe the person who answered the question copy&pasted that text already in its mangled state from somewhere else. (If you google for that string, you will find it on lots of other sites as well.)

Comment: In the question you linked, the OP copy&pasted that code from a bug tracker, where it already appears mangled. So, it seems that it was redacted by that bug tracker. Or, the bug tracker already received it mangled.

Comment: As you can see, the problem has nothing whatsoever to do with Ask Ubuntu. The code was *already* posted in that state to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation.